# What does it mean that in a point Α of an electrical field the voltage is -7?

Tags: theory

The title. I am really confused. Does it mean that you need to spend 7J of energy to move Q=1C from there to somewhere where V=0, does the Q you move matter? Does it mean you need to spend 7J to move Q=1C from V=0 to A and the source of the field is negative?

Comment: It means nothing without units on that -7 number

Answer (score 0):

There no capacitance added to the question nor distance As E fields are in [V/m] just a value with some equipotential plate or probe with very high impedance that gave you a voltage relative to 0V. Nothing else is implied, except assumed in some medium like  air or any electrolyte or dielectric or insulator. (All equivalent except dielectric constant which does not matter here)